# How to convert Tradingview pine script from version 2 to version 3

Tags: pine-script

I want to change the code below from V2 to V3.

I kept trying to change the code, but it kept failing.

```
//@version=2
study("KDJ Indicator", shorttitle="V2_KDJ")
ilong = input(9, title="period")
isig = input(3, title="signal")

bcwsma(s,l,m) => 
    _s = s
    _l = l
    _m = m
    _bcwsma = (_m*_s+(_l-_m)*nz(_bcwsma[1]))/_l
    _bcwsma

c = close
h = highest(high, ilong)
l = lowest(low,ilong)
RSV = 100*((c-l)/(h-l))
pK = bcwsma(RSV, isig, 1)
pD = bcwsma(pK, isig, 1)
pJ = 3 * pK-2 * pD

plot(pJ, color=#4caf50, transp=0)
plot(pK, color=#e91e63, transp=0)
plot(pD, color=#2962ff, transp=0)


bgcolor(pJ>pD? green : red, transp=90)

//h0 = hline(80, color=blue)
//h1 = hline(20, color=red)
h2 = hline(50, color=white)

bullcond = (pJ > 50) and ((crossover(pJ, pK) and pK > pD) or (crossover(pK, pD) and pJ > pK))
alertcondition(bullcond, title = '▲Bullish', message = '▲Bullish')
bearcond = (pJ < 50) and ((crossunder(pJ, pK) and pK < pD) or (crossunder(pK, pD) and pJ < pK))
alertcondition(bearcond, title = '▼Bearish', message = '▼Bearish')
```

Comment: In what way was this code failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only change you need to know about is mentioned here.

Self referencing variables are not allowed anymore. You need to first define the variable and then assign a value to it.

```
//@version=3
study("KDJ Indicator", shorttitle="V2_KDJ")
ilong = input(9, title="period")
isig = input(3, title="signal")

bcwsma(s,l,m) => 
    _s = s
    _l = l
    _m = m
    _bcwsma = 0.0
    _bcwsma := (_m*_s+(_l-_m)*nz(_bcwsma[1]))/_l
    _bcwsma

c = close
h = highest(high, ilong)
l = lowest(low,ilong)
RSV = 100*((c-l)/(h-l))
pK = bcwsma(RSV, isig, 1)
pD = bcwsma(pK, isig, 1)
pJ = 3 * pK-2 * pD

plot(pJ, color=#4caf50, transp=0)
plot(pK, color=#e91e63, transp=0)
plot(pD, color=#2962ff, transp=0)


bgcolor(pJ>pD? green : red, transp=90)

//h0 = hline(80, color=blue)
//h1 = hline(20, color=red)
h2 = hline(50, color=white)

bullcond = (pJ > 50) and ((crossover(pJ, pK) and pK > pD) or (crossover(pK, pD) and pJ > pK))
alertcondition(bullcond, title = '▲Bullish', message = '▲Bullish')
bearcond = (pJ < 50) and ((crossunder(pJ, pK) and pK < pD) or (crossunder(pK, pD) and pJ < pK))
alertcondition(bearcond, title = '▼Bearish', message = '▼Bearish')
```